# How to connect two xml requests on the same javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, xml

I want to display the data from two XML requests on a PHP file through NodeJS. How can this be done? I want to display the flight numbers in the flightDropdown div in the PHP file and I want to display all the details in the myFlights div. It works when I do them separately but not together at the same time. Thanks

liveArrivalsNode.js

```
var xmlhttp;

window.onload=function(){
    init();
}

function init(){            
    getAjaxData();
    getJsonData();
}

function getAjaxData() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function (){
        showAjaxData();
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/arrivals/",true);
    // xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/arrivals/flights",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function showAjaxData()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {       
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        var output ="<table border=1>";
        output += "<tr><th></th><th>Origin</th><th>Airline</th><th>Flight</th><th>Scheduled Date</th><th>Scheduled Time</th><th>Status</th>";
        for(var i=0;i<data.arrivals.length;i++)
        {
            var terminal;
            if(data.arrivals[i].terminal == "t1")
                terminal = "<img src='images/t1.jpg'/>";
            else
                terminal = "<img src='images/t2.jpg'/>";

            output += '<tr>';
            if(data.arrivals[i].highlight == 'on')
                output += "<tr class='highlight'>";
            else
                output += "<tr class='normal'>";

            output += '<td>'+terminal+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].origin+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].airline+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].flight+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].scheduledDate+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].scheduledTime+'</td><td>'+data.arrivals[i].status+ '<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'highlight\' value=\'data.arrivals[i].highlight\'></td></tr>';
        }
        output+="</table>";

        // add output to "fixtures" div
        document.getElementById("myFlights").innerHTML=output;
    }
}

function getJsonData() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function (){
        showJsonData();
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:3000/arrivals/flights",true);

    xmlhttp.send();
}

function showJsonData()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {       
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        var flightDetails = "<form method='GET' action='index.js'>";
        flightDetails += "Filter by Flight No.: " 
        flightDetails += "<select id='flights' name='flight'>";
        flightDetails += "<option value='All'>Any</option>";
        for(var i=0;i<data.flights.length;i++) 
        {
            flightDetails += "<option value="+data.flights[i].flight+">"+data.flights[i].flight+"</option>";
        }
        flightDetails+="</select></form>";

        // add output to "fixtures" div
        document.getElementById("flightDropdown").innerHTML=flightDetails;
    }
}
```

liveArrivalsNode.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colour.css">
        <script src="liveArrivalsNode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php require 'airportArrivals.html'; ?>
        <div id="flightDropdown"></div>
        <p>
            <div id="myFlights"></div>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <caption align="bottom"><hr/><center>L00091898
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: `<caption align="bottom"><hr/><center>L00091898` what is this rule? opening a caption tag than cloring an hr tag than opening a center tag(not supported in html5) and some random text.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried that did not work? I assume the given code is the working (but separated) code?